# How to reduce this equation $y=2px+x^3p^2$ to Clairaut's equation, given that $p=dy/dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have not got any idea about how to reduce it to Clairaut's equation .
I just want to know what should i substitute in order to reduce it to Clairaut's equation of y=px+f(p). I don't need solution , i just want to know what should i substitute.

Comment: Does $p^2$ mean the square of first derivative, or instead means the second derivative?

Comment: @coffeemath $P^2$ mean the square of the first deriavative

Comment: How sure are you that such a transformation exists? Is this obviously part of a relevant exercise section, is there a reference solution?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann the solution is 1+xy=0

Comment: Yes, that is the critical curve of the discriminant that you get when analyzing the quadratic completion $1+xy=(1+x^2p)^2$. But it is no solution, or you have some sign missing.

Comment: I do not think you can convert it to Clairaut ODE.